# React typescript, useReducer TS2769: No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently reaching out for help as typescript gave me the following error that I cannot just make sense of it when trying to write a useReducer.

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer:
> ReducerWithoutAction, initializerArg: any, initializer?:
> undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
>     Argument of type '(state: AuthState, action: AuthAction) => Error | { wallet: string | null; profile: { [key: string]: Object[]; } |
> null; account: { [key: string]: Object[]; } | null; error: { [key:
> string]: Object[]; } | null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'ReducerWithoutAction'.   Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state:
> AuthState, action: AuthAction) => Error | { wallet: string | null;
> profile: { [key: string]: Object[]; } | null; account: { [key:
> string]: Object[]; } | null; error: { ...; } | null; }, initialState:
> never, initializer?: undefined): [...]', gave the following error.
>     Argument of type 'AuthState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

```
import React from 'react'

type AuthState = {
    wallet: string | null,
    profile: { [key: string]: Object[] } | null,
    account: { [key: string]: Object[] } | null,
    error: { [key: string]: Object[] } | null,
}

type AuthAction = {
    type: 'SET_WALLET' | 'SET_ACCOUNT' | 'SET_ERROR' | 'LOGOUT',
    payload: AuthState
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
    wallet: null,
    profile: null,
    account: null,
    error: null
}

const authReducer = (state: AuthState, action: AuthAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_WALLET':
            return {...state, wallet: action.payload.wallet}
        case 'SET_ACCOUNT':
            return {...state, profile: action.payload.profile, account: action.payload.account}
        case 'SET_ERROR':
            return {...state, error: action.payload.error}
        case 'LOGOUT':
            return {...state, wallet: action.payload.wallet}
        default:
            return new Error(`Unhandled  action type ${action.type}`)
    }
}

const AuthContext = React.createContext(initialState)

type Props = {
    children: JSX.Element
}

const AuthProvider = ({children}: Props) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(authReducer, initialState)
    const value = {state, dispatch}
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export {AuthContext, AuthProvider}
```

If only someone could help me understand whys that is and what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
default:
  return new Error(`Unhandled  action type ${action.type}`);
```

The reason you're getting a type error is because of this line. If this case is reached, then you'll return an error object, replacing your state with that instead of an `AuthState` object.

If you're just wanting to log an error, you could do:

```
default: 
  console.error(`Unhandled action type ${action.type}`);
  return state;
```

If you want it to blow up instead, you could throw an error:

```
default:
  throw new Error(`Unhandled  action type ${action.type}`)
```

Or if the code is correct and you want your state to be replaced with an error object, you can change the type of the reducer to know that Error is a possibility:

```
const authReducer = (state: AuthState | Error, action: AuthAction) => {
```

Comment: cheers mate, it all makes sense now. 
i wish the typescript error was clearer about this :D

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the errors can be a bit cryptic. In case it helps for future debugging, here's what i did to figure it out: i took your code, and then gave the function an explicit return type. Ie, `const authReducer = (state: AuthState, action: AuthAction): AuthState => {`. This completely changed the error message it showed, and also moved the error indicator to the default case. Sometimes making the types more explicit can help typescript point out the problem better.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I will do that from now on in the future.
also, now I've noticed the value inside the AuthContext.Provider shows an error message 
`TS2739: Type '{ state: AuthState; dispatch: Dispatch<AuthAction>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AuthState': wallet, profile, account, error  index.d.ts(338, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<AuthState>'` Any idea what that could be?

Comment: `const AuthContext = React.createContext(initialState)` Based on this line, typescript is expecting you to pass just an `AuthState` object as the value, but instead you're passing an object with a `state` property and a `dispatch` property. Try doing `const AuthContext = React.createContext({ state: initialState, dispatch: () => {} });`

Comment: `TS2322: Type '{ state: AuthState; dispatch: React.Dispatch<AuthAction>; }' is not assignable to type '{ state: AuthState; dispatch: () => void; }'.   Types of property 'dispatch' are incompatible.     Type 'Dispatch<AuthAction>' is not assignable to type '() => void'.  index.d.ts(338, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<{ state: AuthState; dispatch: () => void; }>'`
Now its giving me this

Comment: Ok, so instead of a void function it will need to be a function that returns a valid state object. `dispatch: () => initialState`, for example

Comment: with that solution, a different problem would come up, but regardless I've found a good blogpost that explains it. The solution was `React.Dispatch<AuthAction>;`  
https://dev.to/elisealcala/react-context-with-usereducer-and-typescript-4obm